# Should I delete my question or accept my own answer?

Tags: discussion

Yesterday I have asked [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24499530/swift-cllocationmanager-not-asking-for-user-permission) question, until now nobody gives an answer, just two user pointed  out it could be duplicated, the given links are about IOS, I was asking about OS X also one user raised close vote. 
Eventually I realise what is wrong. I forgot to give proper entitlements in App Sandbox settings, when I select correct entitlement problem solved. Then I wrote the solution as an answer.

Now I am thinking, I should delete my question because there is a chance nobody can guess what I did or didn't on configuration, at the other hand this could be useful to someone else who made same mistake. Now the question is, should I accept my answer or should I delete my question?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I would say leave it. The question is different enough and the solution unique enough that it adds value to SO.

The question you need to ask is could someone else have this problem. Then will this solution possibly fix the problem for someone else. If both are yes than it is likely an ok post. Keep it

Comment: And [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24499530/swift-cllocationmanager-not-asking-for-user-permission) is the question in question (I guess).

Comment: yes, i believe it is

Comment: yes that is the question and thank you, I discovered meta little bit late but it is great place to learn about SO.